# Click to go next position in live animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created an animation that goes from right to left, and I am trying to add some jump on click of **next box** button.

How can I apply it using JavaScript ?

`nextBox` function should apply the jump from box1 to box2 and so on... ( for example )

```js
const nextBox = () => {
  alert("nextBox");
  // replace => Jump to next box position +=100px to right
};
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  background-color: aqua;
  height: fit-content;
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.anim {
  animation: anim 30s infinite linear;
  display: flex;
}

.anim > .box {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.container > button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 32px;
  width: 50px;
}

@keyframes anim {
  to {
    transform: translateX(-1000px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="anim">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <button onclick="nextBox()">next box</button>
</div>
```

codepen [here](https://codepen.io/lichaytiram/pen/poRNMpL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following implementation should work since it does what you want.

Here we have another `boxContainer` div to apply `transition` to and let the `animation` remain on `anim` class wrapper div. Also we can have another `div` of class `pseudoBox` whose `width` we increase by `100px` to fill out the empty spacing we encounter later and to keep the order of `box` divs constant, we keep on appending the **first** `box` class div at the end in a cyclic fashion. I have **numbered** the boxes for better understanding. So our original no of `box` divs remain constant.

```js
let jump = 0;
const anim = document.querySelector('.anim');
const boxContainer = document.querySelector('.boxContainer');
const pseudoBox = document.querySelector('.pseudoBox');

const animate = () => {
  boxContainer.style.transform = `translate(${jump}px)`;
  pseudoBox.style.width = `${jump*-1}px`;
  boxContainer.appendChild(boxContainer.children[1]);
}

const nextBox = () => {
  jump -= 100;
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
};
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  background-color: aqua;
  height: fit-content;
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.anim {
  animation: anim 30s infinite linear;
}

.pseudoBox {
  flex-shrink: 0
}

.boxContainer {
  display: flex;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}

.boxContainer>.box {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
}

.container>button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 32px;
  width: 50px;
}

@keyframes anim {
  to {
    transform: translateX(-1000px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="anim animateStuff">

    <div class="boxContainer">
      <div class="pseudoBox"></div>
      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
      <div class="box">6</div>
      <div class="box">7</div>
      <div class="box">8</div>
      <div class="box">9</div>
      <div class="box">10</div>
      <div class="box">11</div>
      <div class="box">12</div>
      <div class="box">13</div>
      <div class="box">14</div>
      <div class="box">15</div>
      <div class="box">16</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button onclick="nextBox()">next box</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your answer it work as I ask with click button. You can fix the issue that animation jump in some point? (he restart instead keep going)

Answer (score 2):

With my solution I converted the css keyframe to the javascript animation loop. You probably didn't want that but I just found it a lot easier to control this animation with javascript, as you wanted to go to the next box, rather than just +100.
I used CSS variables in the :root to control the translateX of the anim element.
Hope it's what you were after

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="anim">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <button>next box</button>
</div>
```

```
:root {
  --tX: 'transform: translateX(0px)';
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  background-color: aqua;
  height: fit-content;
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.anim {
  transform: var(--tX);
  display: flex;
}

.anim > .box {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.container > button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 32px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('button')

const anim = document.querySelector('.anim')
  let computed = window.getComputedStyle(anim) // get the computed style (read the transform property)

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  // Get the transform property
  let transform = computed['-webkit-transform']
  // read it from the css matrix(n,n,n,n,n,n)
  //  also negate the value to make rounding easier for me
  let tX = -1 * parseInt(transform.split(',')[4].trim());

  // this gives us the translateX value
  
  // round up to nearest 100 - box size
  //  take 10 - account for margin
  tX = (Math.ceil(tX/100)*100) - 10
  
  // negate again 
  tX *= -1
  
  console.log(tX)
  
  // set our CSS variable to this value
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--tX', `translateX(${tX}px)`)
})

// animation loop
function loop() {
  // get the transform property each frame
  let transform = computed['-webkit-transform']
  let tX = 0;
  try {
    tX = transform.split(',')[4].trim();    
  } catch (TypeError) { 
    // probably because of being not applied in css yet
    tX = 0;
  }
  
  // loop the translateX - don't go below -1000
  if (tX <= -1000) {
    tX = 0;
  }

  // perform animation by subtracting 2 from translateX each frame
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--tX', `translateX(${tX-2}px)`)
  
  // perform this at 60FPS
  setTimeout(() => {
    requestAnimationFrame(loop)    
  }, 1000 / 60)
}
loop()
```

also link to codepen
https://codepen.io/sean-b765/pen/rNjjLxM

Answer (score 0):

after I saw @Lakshya Thakur answer to my post I found another way to achieve it
with clean html and CSS, without pseudoBox element only JavaScript way

```js
let jump = 0;
let index = 0;

const boxContainer = document.querySelector(".boxContainer");

const animate = () => {
  boxContainer.style.transform = `translate(${jump}px)`;
  boxContainer.appendChild(boxContainer.children[index].cloneNode(true));
  index++;
};

const nextBox = () => {
  jump -= 100;
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
};
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  background-color: aqua;
  height: fit-content;
  width: 500px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.anim {
  animation: anim 30s infinite linear;
}

.boxContainer {
  display: flex;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}

.boxContainer > .box {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: blue;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
}

.container > button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 32px;
  width: 50px;
}

@keyframes anim {
  to {
    transform: translateX(-1000px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="anim">

    <div class="boxContainer">
      <div class="box">1</div>
      <div class="box">2</div>
      <div class="box">3</div>
      <div class="box">4</div>
      <div class="box">5</div>
      <div class="box">6</div>
      <div class="box">7</div>
      <div class="box">8</div>
      <div class="box">9</div>
      <div class="box">10</div>
      <div class="box">11</div>
      <div class="box">12</div>
      <div class="box">13</div>
      <div class="box">14</div>
      <div class="box">15</div>
      <div class="box">16</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button onclick="nextBox()">next box</button>
</div>
```

credit to Lakshya Thakur for first idea